# Using gdaltransform to extract first value in geoTIFF

Tags: gdal

I have a geoTIFF file and I want to only extract the pixel value for 0,0 and write it to a text file. I would like to do this without using any heavy code - using the command line in Windows. I have found  [a webpage here that shows how that can be done in gdal in the command line.](https://csmojo.com/posts/how-to-use-gdal-python-to-transform-geotiff-pixels-to-lat-lon-real-word-coordinates.html)

In their example, they show it can be done by this method :

```
gdaltransform myImage.tiff
0 0
```

However, that prompts the user to input the required data cells. I tried doing the following :

```
gdaltransform myImage.tiff 0,0 >> out.txt
```

This does not work as it gives the following error :
"ERROR 4: 0,0: No such file or directory".

Is there a way to get this to run in the command prompt without user input? Am I building the command line script wrong or using gdal wrong?

Comment: If you want upper left coordinate you can use `gdalinfo myImage.tiff | grep "Upper Left"` this will result in `Upper Left  (  -8.8701000,  61.1224000) (  8d52'12.36"W, 61d 7'20.64"N)` and to save file add `>> textfilename.txt`

Comment: Please edit your question from `I want to only extract the pixel value for 0,0`. Actually it appears from the link that you provided that you are not interested in the pixel values but in the georeferenced coordinates of the pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gdallocationinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html but the form of the report is probably not exactly as you would like it to be.

```
gdallocationinfo test.tif 0 0
Report:
  Location: (0P,0L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 32
  Band 2:
    Value: 30
  Band 3:
    Value: 31
```

Comment: This is, in fact - exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "heredoc" to provide the input:

```
gdaltransform myImage.tiff << EOF
0 0
EOF
```